# get an element index in ocl collection ? [ocl_Eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, ocl

i'm working on the following domain :

[my domain diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6o48.png)

i want to express the folowing constraint : 
" a succession of two actions of Type Rotate is not allowed "
i tried this declaration but **eclipse is not recognizing indexOf(element ) :**

```
class Choreography
{
    property actions : Action[+|1] { ordered composes };
    attribute name : String[?];

    /*Succession of two actions of Type is not permitted */

    invariant rotate_succ:
    self.actions->asSequence()->forAll(a1:Action,a2:Action
        |

        a1.oclIsTypeOf(Rotate) and (indexOf(a1)=indexOf(a2)+1) implies  
        not a2.oclIsTypeOf(Rotate)
    )


    ;
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to work with the index of a random element from an ocl colletion ?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
OrderedCollection(T):indexOf(obj : OclAny[?]) : Integer[1]
```

operation requires an OrderedCollection (Sequence/OrderedSet) as its source and an OclAny as its argument. You have not identified a source so OCL will consider first an implicit iterator leading to an

```
a1.indexOf(a1)
a2.indexOf(a1)
```

ambiguity which would be an error if an Action had an indexOf operation. Then it considers an implicit self which also fails since there is no Choreography.indexOf() operation.

I presume you meant

```
self.actions->indexOf(a1)
```

etc etc, or more readably put self.actions in a let-variable for multi-use.

(Use of oclIsTypeOf is very rarely right. Use oclIsKindOf unless you have a specific intent.)

(self.actions is already an OrderedCollection so there is no need for the asSequence()).

Your use of indexOf will lead to quadratic performance. Better to use indexes - something like:

```
let theActions = self.actions in
    Sequence{1..theActions->size()-1}->forAll(index |
      theActions->at(index).oclIsKindOf(Rotate)
      implies not theActions->at(index+1).oclIsKindOf(Rotate))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! actually that was my error i should have used the synthax you have mentionned :  self.actions->indexOf(a1)  now it's working with it !